# counting integers in modular function

Tags: modular-arithmetic, factorial

- Given a set of n positive integers.
- Say A={ 3,4,6,7,8}
- We have to find a number of integers in set that follow this property.
- property { factorial(x) mod (x+1) = x }
- here 3 and 7 are those numbers.
- 2! % 3 = 2
- 6! % 7 = 6
- Here there are two such numbers.
- How to deal with this type of questions.
- I don't even know how to start.

Comment: Hint: [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem).

Comment: It was a great help